# SerialVersion UID Java - How SerialVersionUID work?

Tags: java, serializable, serialversionuid

Hello I've one question about `SerialVersionUID` in Java.
If I generate a `SerialVersionUID` for `class A`, 
2 instances of `A` have the same `SerialVersion` about class and another unique Serial for the object, different about `object1` and `object2`? Or how? 
I don't understand, please reply me. Thanks.

Comment: SerialVersionUID is a static field, therefore it "belongs" to the class, not to any of the instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SerialVersionUID is way to identify a class's version. So all objects of the same class will have the same SerialVersionUID.
However if you make change to the class, it is recommended to change the SerialVersionUID. And then in case of incompatibility, the serialization of the object would fail.

See: [What is a serialVersionUID and why should I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285793/what-is-a-serialversionuid-and-why-should-i-use-it)

Answer (score 0):

1. > serialVersionUID is used for version control of object.
2. If we  don’t define serialVersionUID in the class, and any
   modification is made in class, then we will be unable to deSerialize
   our class because serialVersionUID generated by java compiler for
   modified class will be different from old serialized object and
   deserialization process will end up throwing
   java.io.InvalidClassException
3. The serialization at runtime associates with each serializable class
   a version number, called a serialVersionUID, which is used during
   deserialization to ***verify that the sender and receiver of a
   serialized object have loaded classes for that object that are
   compatible with respect to serialization***.

> serialVersionUID object1 and object2?

It will be same, as serial version uid is static (i.e. class level)